# Deny vibrations (except my app) while my app is running

Tags: java, android, accessibility, vibration, android-vibration

I want to create an android app for blind people, so I **don't want vibrations** from **outside my app**, like notifications or other apps, otherwise those would change the pattern. How can I do it programmatically using Java?

Comment: Just set the ringer to silence when your app is running and then turn the ringer back on to vibrate right before your app vibrates and then after it vibrates put it back on scilence

Comment: that could be a way to do that , but is it possible that we can put phone on silent from our app in nougat and above? @SteelToe

Comment: Yes, I have a helper class that can do it. Would you like me to post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SteelToe said:

> Just set the ringer to silence when your app is running and then turn the ringer back on to vibrate right before your app vibrates and then after it vibrates put it back on scilence

So you could use code like:

```
function vibrateOn(){
    audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
    audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
}

function vibrateOff(){
    audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
    audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the options.

```
switch (position) {
 case 0:
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
       break;
 case 1:
     audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
       break;
case 2:
     audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
      audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, 
         AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
       break;
 case 3:
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, 
        AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
    break;
 }
```